# Curved roof (attic)?

Tags: modeling

Apologies if this comes across as a stupid question, but I was wondering what might be the best way to achieve the curved attic (roof?) part of this building?

[image]

My gut says add a cube and add some cuts to pinch in the middle sections, but I'm not sure how to convert that into a smooth curve!

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hi! There are multiple ways but subsurf, proportional edits and maybe lattice deform could be worth trying maybe

Comment: yes a cube that gets smaller to its top, put a subsurf if you want to smooth the angles, and some additional edge loops to sharp the edges a bit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As has been commented, a subdiv. approach might be:

[image]

- To inset the top face of a cuboid evenly: <kbd>I</kbd> inset it with 'Even' checked..
- Select the outside vertices and  <kbd>G</kbd><kbd>G</kbd> slide the loop inwards
- <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>M</kbd> merge the top vertices by distance.

[image]

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>R</kbd> cut loop round the waist
- Assign a Bevel modifier, by angle.
- These are my Bevel settings, quite a common way to put in holding loops to contain  Catmull-Clark subdivision, in the right circumstances.

[image]

- (You can, instead, use Bevel Weights, or introduce holding loops by hand)
- Assign a Subdivision surface modifier, probably 1 level of Catmull-Clark will do

[image]

You can adjust the curvature by adjusting the one loop around the waist, (at least, to block the model out).

Comment: hey! Thanks for this! Would it be possible for you to explain the bevel modifier part? Struggling to see what I'm doing wrong with that part!

Comment: It's ok, I figured it out! Thank you!

Comment: @OliverPrimus hehe.. too late! (See Edit)

Comment: hahah thank you!